# An issue after testing

Tags: objective-c, xcode, testing, memory, crash

I have not been testing my app for a long time. After testing I have this

[image]

What does it mean? What should I check?

Comment: If you're certain that the file is there try cleaning the project (Product - Clean) and then deleting the Derived Data (from the organiser window) before building again.

Comment: doesn't help. other ways?

Comment: is it important at all? I mean, if app works fine? Does Apple refuse, if there is a small issue by testing, not by running?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken that looks like it'll stop the app from building? You won't be able to build it in order to send it to Apple. But yes, as long as the app does what it says then Apple will accept. They are not there to check bugs, just to check it does what you've said it does.

Comment: OK. It doesn't stop from building. All works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go into your project “Build Settings” and look for the “Prefix Header” line and delete it. In this screenshot I just deleted mine. (They’re not needed any more if you’re using modules.)

[image]

Comment: well, it looks helpfull but doesnt't help - that is weird. some other ideas?

Comment: also,there are still some files with prefix.Is it anyway already, or should I change their names?